# Subclassing UICollectionViewCell, silly issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to use a subclassed UICollectionViewCell I created.

The only difference in my subclass is that the cell has an imageView property.
I'm doing everything programatically - no storyboards or NIBs

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PFUICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FlickrCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [self generateRandomUIColor];


    NSURL *staticPhotoURL = [self.context photoSourceURLFromDictionary:[self.photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] size:OFFlickrSmallSize];



    **if (cell.imageView) {**

        cell.imageView = [self.pfImageViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;

    }

}
```

However when I try to check if the cells imageView property is instantiated, I get,

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

It's nearly like the cell doesn't know it's a PFUICollectionViewCell and still thinks it's a UICollectionViewCell.

I know this is a simple thing but I don't know what i'm doing wrong,

Thanks,
John

Comment: Have you set breakpoints and ensured that the cell is indeed a PFUICollectionViewCell? You can do so by `NSLog(NSStringFromClass([cell class]);` or I believe if you have a breakpoint after the cell is set it might just tell you.

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't seem to be! It's quite strange, it still thinks it's a UICollectionViewCell, however all my other subclassed objects, are working fine! do I have to cast it after the dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier call?

Comment: Try casting after but I don't believe so...there's no way a regular UICollectionViewCell could have ever been created with that identifier ("FlickrCell")?

Comment: I even cast like this right after the dequeue call:     cell = (PFUICollectionViewCell *) cell;
 and it still thinks it's a UICollectionViewCell! --- I don't know what to do, weird right?

Comment: My only guess is that somewhere a UICollectionViewCell was instantiated with that reusable identifier "FlickrCell"

Comment: Ahh I found it! I had     [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FlickrCell"]; - not sure why this would override the explicit declaration of the cell type?! but hey at least it's working - if you want to add as the answer i'll mark as correct - thanks for the help

Comment: check in storyboard , if you have given class name to your collectionview cell to PFUICollectionViewCell

Comment: It's fine, glad I could help

Comment: @JohnWoods What explicit declaration of the type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add code below in your `-viewDidLoad` method (or just after you created UICollectionView instance):

```
[collectionView registerClass:[PFUICollectionViewCell class]
   forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FlickrCell"];
```

**UPD:**

Oups, haven't seen this answer in comments.